# Inspiration for Red Impulse in Science Ninja Team Gatchaman

Tags: anime, inspiration, gatchaman

I've been rewatching Science Ninja Team Gathcaman and my wife, who is Japanese, asked if the character of Red Impulse and his team of formation flying red jets was inspired by or named after the Japanese air display team called Blue Impulse. (If you don't know Blue Impulse they are the Japanese equivalent to the Red Arrows in the UK, or the Thunderbirds and the Blue Angels in the US.)

A quick Google search turned up [this page](https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Blue_Impulse) which claims:

> The mercenary air team "Red Impulse" and its leader from the anime series Science Ninja Team Gatchaman take their name from the Blue Impulse.

However this page does not seem to list any sources. Does anyone know if this is actually correct? If so can you point me to any more detailed information.

Comment: I suspect that there's no source because it's too obvious to need a source. Like the [uniforms in Starship Troopers](http://www.snakkle.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/nph_starship_GC1.jpg) looking a bit,y'know, Nazi-esque

Answer (score 1):

There's a long history of doing references [like this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoHistoricalFiguresWereHarmed). I have found no sources for this, but I think it's a clear trope.

There's no evidence for or against this. And 2ch gave me w for asking. So I doubt you will find any evidence of it.

Comment: The question was if it was a direct homage; do you have any evidence that it was?

Comment: Welcome to the site. While I suspect that your answer is accurate, we prefer more substance to our answers here.  Could you edit your answer to include more examples of this sort of reference in similar works, or perhaps any creators positively acknowledging the connection in interviews?

Comment: For anyone confused by the 2nd to last sentence, "I asked the Japanese internet users of 2channel and they just said 'lol'"